# HTML Variables ignores double brackets

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-2015

The actually problem was that my angular is not working at all

if you want to test this do this :

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

     ngOnInit() {
        console.log('test');
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////

I'm trying to create a dropdownlist with a name and value different from each other. In Visual studio 2015 the brackets at ">{{directionOption.name}}<" are shown grey as plain text

```
<select [(ngModel)]="direction">
<option *ngFor="#directionOption of directionOptions" [value]="directionOption.value">{{directionOption.name}}</option>
</select>
```

same result

```
<select [(ngModel)]="direction">
<option *ngFor="let directionOption of directionOptions" [value]="directionOption.value">{{directionOption.name}}</option>
</select>



export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

direction: any = { 'Left': 'L' };
directionOptions: any = [{ name: 'Left', value: 'L' }, { name: 'Right', value: 'R' }, { name: 'None', value: 'N' }];
}
```

The current result inside browser F12

```
<option *ngfor="#directionOption of directionOptions" [value]="directionOption.value">{{directionOption.name}}</option>
```

[image: These variable names are in the same setup as above, just dutch]

Comment: `directionOptions` doesn't have a `name`

Comment: Yes. @GünterZöchbauer is correct.

Comment: which name am i missing @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: And wait a minute, you don't  have proper data in directionOptions data.

Comment: If "the current result inside browser F12" actually is shown in your browsers devtools, then there is something seriously wrong with your app. Angular2 doesn't process bindings added dynamically to the DOM, only when they are added statically to a components template.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer conclusion, my angular2 is not working at all first time working in C# angular 2

Answer (score 1):

Use `let` keyword instead of `#`,

```
<option *ngfor="let directionOption of directionOptions" [value]="directionOption.value">{{directionOption.name}}</option>
```

Comment: Tried that, no difference it seems

Comment: what's the exact problem?

Comment: quite possibly that my array cant work with a *ngFor, possibly I need to adjust that

Comment: correct directionOptions with proper value as shown by @Gaunter.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

Angular2 doesn't process bindings added dynamically to the DOM, only when they are added statically to a components template.

**original**

`directionOptions` should look like

```
directionOptions: any = [{ name: 'Left' , value: 'L' }, { name: 'Right' , value: 'R' }, { name: 'None' , value: 'N' }];
```